# How to get GetFolder(IID_ExplorerPaneVisibility) calls

Tags: c++, windows, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I am new to Namespace Extensions. I'm trying to disable the Navigation pane for a Namespace Extension.

I have my Shell View Implementation implement IFolderView:: GetFolder which returns a IShellFolder object. The Shell Folder class is implementing the IExplorerPaneVisibility::GetPaneState method.

But I'm not getting GetFolder(IID_ExplorerPaneVisibility) calls. Can someone help me with this?

```
STDMETHODIMP ShellFolderViewImpl::GetFolder(REFIID riid, VOID ** ppv)
{
    if (riid == IID_IExplorerPaneVisibility)
    {
       this->QueryInterface(riid, (void**)ppv);
    }
    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP ShellFolderViewImpl::GetPaneState(REFEXPLORERPANE ep,EXPLORERPANESTATE * peps)
{
    if (ep == EP_NavPane)
        *peps = EPS_DEFAULT_OFF;
    else if (ep == EP_Commands)
        *peps = EPS_DEFAULT_OFF;
    else if (ep == EP_DetailsPane)
        *peps = EPS_DEFAULT_OFF;
    else if (ep == EP_AdvQueryPane)
        *peps = EPS_DEFAULT_OFF;
    else if (ep == EP_QueryPane)
        *peps = EPS_DEFAULT_OFF;
    else
        *peps = EPS_DONTCARE;
    return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN says

> The IExplorerPaneVisibility implementation is retrieved from the Shell
>   folder. The Shell folder, in turn, is retrieved from the view.

I interpret this as; it is going to QueryInterface your IShellFolder to get your IExplorerPaneVisibility implementation.

You should also check [this newsgroup thread](http://microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell.narkive.com/eeyV7YsU/iexplorerpanevisibility-problems-in-vista), it shows a couple of workarounds you might need to turn off some of the panes.

I hope your code here is not your real implementation, you should never return S_OK in GetFolder for things you don't recognize!